# Java - Connect Four game wont stack different counters above three

Tags: java, eclipse

I cannot work out why counters wont stack above 3 when there are different counters in that column. For example, in the image below, you can see that the first 3 counters are placed fine. However, if I try to place a counter in the second column for a fourth consecutive time, nothing is added and the board stays the same.

[image]

This is puzzling me, because it only seems to be happening when different counters are used in the same column. In the image below, you can see that it works fine when four counters of the same kind are placed.

[image]

Would somebody mind looking at my code to help identify the problem?

```
private void placeCounter(char player, int position){
    boolean placed = false;


    if(player == 'r'){
        for( int i=board.length-1; i>=0; i--){
            if(!placed){
                if(board[i][position] == 'y'){
                    board[i-1][position] = 'r';
                    placed = true;
                }

                else if(board[i][position] != 'r'){
                    board[i][position] = 'r';
                    placed = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        for( int i=board.length-1; i>=0; i--){
            if(!placed){
                if(board[i][position] == 'r'){
                    board[i-1][position] = 'y';
                    placed = true;
                }

                else if(board[i][position] != 'y'){
                    board[i][position] = 'y';
                    placed = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is `boardWidth` and `boardHeight` `7`, but your board `char[6][7]`?

Comment: Apologies, it is still a work in process. Is this what is causing the problem?

Comment: No, but I was just wondering.

Comment: Btw, you got an issue in your "winning" logic. You don't have to have 4 "connected", just 4 "inside one row" to win. (From line ~127 to 153.) You have to reset the `count` variable in the else blocks.

Comment: Consider using an enum for cell content instead of "r" or "y". This can even hold an "Empty" content. You'd initialize your complete board with empty at first, so you only have to look for not empty cells in your "placeCounter". With that you can eleminate a lot of duplicate code, just by iterating over "CellContent.r/CellContent.y".
Furthermore replace "i" and "j" by "row" and "column", which will give you a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Your `placeCounter` method should be something like this:

```
private void placeCounter(char player, int position) {
        boolean placed = false;

        if (player == 'r') {
            for (int i = board.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (!placed && board[i - 1][position] != 'r' && board[i - 1][position] != 'y') {
                    if (board[i][position] == 'y') {
                        board[i - 1][position] = 'r';
                        placed = true;
                    }

                    else if (board[i][position] != 'r') {
                        board[i][position] = 'r';
                        placed = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = board.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (!placed && board[i - 1][position] != 'y' && board[i - 1][position] != 'r') {
                    if (board[i][position] == 'r') {
                        board[i - 1][position] = 'y';
                        placed = true;
                    }

                    else if (board[i][position] != 'y') {
                        board[i][position] = 'y';
                        placed = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When you try to place the counter, you must check if the cell is already occupied by `r` or `y`. If you notice I added this conditions to `if(!placed)` instruction:

```
&& board[i - 1][position] != 'y' && board[i - 1][position] != 'r'
```

If you don't do this control, you will end always overriding the same cell, and that's why nothing is added after the fourth time.

You have also to check if user input is `r` or `y`, because if I insert a space or a number as input the program throw an exception.

This is a rough solution, you might came with something better, but is just to put you in the right direction.

Comment: This is causing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when filling up row `0` and `1` randomly.

Comment: Yes I know, infact I wrote that this is a rough solution just to put him in the right direction, is not the definitive solution. He asked why the counter wasn't added after the fourth time, not to do his homeworks